# How to check an input from two different format provided by Programmer in C++

Tags: c++, input

Does Anyone Knows how can i check input from the user that whether it is in given one of the given formats or not.

I want user to enter a complex number either in form of **a+ib or a+bi or a or bi** (he/she should write it only once in Console.) and we should detect the format.

It can be Done by taking string as input but that makes the code much more complexer.I want an intresting,Simpler method for it.

A sample code that i thought should work is given but it only works in first case Written in if condition.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter The Complex Number : ";
    double real=0,img=0;
    char sign,iota='i';

    if(cin >> real >> sign >> img >> iota || cin >> real >> sign >> iota >> img || cin >> real || cin >> img >> iota)
    {
        cout << real << " " << img << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed !\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because if you get a error half way the first case through you cannot recover to check the second case. I'm afraid the more complex code is the only option. You should look into the support C++ has for regular expressions which will make this task a whole lot easier.

Comment: @john I tried , but could't find any way to make it simpler and efficient.The last Option was posting this Quotien

Comment: Use `std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s);` to get the line, then parse s until it matches one of your formats.  If it fails all formats, then it is a reject (syntax error).

Comment: @Eljay I Tried it but the time complexity , space , efficiency is much more higher in that case.

Comment: Did you considered to ask the client to input a sign that will help you understand which form of input he will use / did used? Something like: `std::cin >> special_char; if (special_char == 'a') ...`?

Comment: The space or time complexity of parsing a line isn't going to be any different. @Eljay's suggestion to use `std::getline` would work just fine. You could then use `std::string::find` to look for a `+` and split the string at its index, if necessary.

Comment: Suggestion: When you have performance requirements specify them clearly in the question;otherwise, you're going to get answers that tend towards the simplest, easiest and most fool-proof.

Answer (score 0):

Read the input into a string and check each possible format:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::optional<std::pair<double, double>> parse(const std::string &line) {  
    double real = 0, img = 0;
    char sign, iota;
    {
    std::stringstream l(line);
    if (l >> real >> sign >> img >> iota && iota == 'i' && (sign == '+' || sign == '-'))
        return std::pair(real, sign == '+' ? img : -img);
    }
    {
    std::stringstream l(line);
    if (l >> real >> sign >> iota >> img && iota == 'i' && (sign == '+' || sign == '-'))
        return std::pair(real, sign == '+' ? img : -img);
    }
    {
    std::stringstream l(line);
    if (l >> img >> iota && iota == 'i')
        return std::pair(0, img);
    }
    {
    std::stringstream l(line);
    if (l >> real)
        return std::pair(real, 0);
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter The Complex Number : ";

    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    const auto c(parse(line));
    if (c) {
        const auto [real, img] = *c;
        std::cout << real << " " << img << std::endl;
    } else
        std::cout << "Failed !\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I created a function to parse the input. It returns an optional containing a pair it was successful. If it fails it returns an empty optional. The order of the checks is important. You can't check

```
if (l >> real)
```

before

```
if (l >> img >> iota)
```

I added some checks for `iota` and `sign`.